# how to grab the uploaded file from charles network utility

Tags: http-proxy, charles-proxy

I'l like to save and extract the file part from a multipart http upload recorded by Charles network utility on the mac.  Is there a way to do this?  For instance, I can see the jpeg files contents in the request text, but if I try to copy and paste that into a file, it is an invalid file.  I'd like to simply just save to disk the file that was captured.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using Charles 4.1.3:

- Right-click request in Structure pane
- Select "Export..."
- Select Format "HTTP Trace File (.trace)", name the file
- Open the file in a text editor, such as TextMate. When asked for encoding, Western - ISO Latin 1 is just fine
- Remove all text from the start that contains header info, up until and including the line that says something like "Request-Body:<<--EOF-1498740958503-"
- Scroll all the way down, and remove all text starting at the line that looks like this: "--EOF-1498741139055-"
- Save
- Preview will already be an image. When renamed to the actual format, more information, such as image size, will become available